# ASP.NET Getting TextBox.Text using TextBox.Tag

Tags: asp.net, properties, textbox, tags

I am having a Grid in which there are many textboxes and in their respective Tag Property of each textbox ,i am having a unique numerical value 1,2,3......etc.On the basis of looping i want to access the "TextBox.Text" value.

How can i loop through each text box in Grid and access the TextBox.Text using TextBox.Tag

Please help me?

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET  a [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) does _not_ have a `Tag` property, so what are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry in wpf I am having tag property of textbox

Comment: But your question is still full of ASP.NET.

Comment: Sorry my .xaml file is having textboxes and in .xaml.cs file I want to write code .I am new to this